# apache RewriteRule not working correctly

Tags: apache-httpd

I am trying to do the following with Apache:

If I ask for http(s)://domain.local(/) I should be redirected to a completely new domain like this https://www.domain_new.local

If I ask for http://domain.local/gp I should be redirected to https://domain.local/gp

I tried the following, but doesn't seem to work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.local

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    
    # html directory contains gp directory 
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}" "^domain\.local\/?$"
    RewriteRule "^domain\.local\/?$" "https://domain_new.local"

    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}" "^domain\.local\/gp(.*)"
    RewriteRule "^/?(.*)" "https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1"
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.local

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/" 
    
    SSLEngine on
    
    # html directory contains gp directory     
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain.local.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domain.local.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain.local.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: plz help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is much simpler that I was thinking. You simply redirect all HTTP to HTTPS and then handle the actual rewrite in 443 virtual host, thanks to @Hauke Laging who pointed out that actual redirection should occur in 443 virtual host and also errors in the RegEx I was using. This article [How to force https, www and a trailing slash with one redirect](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/https-www-and-trailing-slash) is interesting read as well.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.local

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    
    # html directory contains gp directory 
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.local

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}" "^domain\.local\/?$"
    RewriteRule .* https://domain_new.local
    
    SSLEngine on
    
    # html directory contains gp directory     
    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain.local.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domain.local.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain.local.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it but I notice several (potential) problems:

- `RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}" "^domain\.local\/?$"`
  The `\` before the `/` may be a problem. In general there is no reason to involve `REQUEST_URI` in `RewriteCond` as you have it in the `RewriteRule` line again.
- `RewriteRule "^domain\.local\/?$"`
  The domain does not belong there. `RewriteRule` matches the `REQUEST_URI` only.
- The rewrite rule for `https://domain.local` is missing in the HTTPS configuration.

Comment: thank you for your answer, how can I catch that the URL contains only domain.local and rewrite it. This is the problem I am currently facing to be honest. I think I only need a rule that redirects if URL only equals domain.local.

Comment: @elekgeek `RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^domain\.local$"` As the problem is solved you should accept my answer.

Comment: %{HTTP_HOST} alone doesn't work, you must include %{REQUEST_URI} because you won't be able to find out if the user wants gp or not, read my answer again.

Comment: @elekgeek As I already pointed out in my answer: There is no need for `REQUEST_URI` in the `RewriteCond` line because that value appears (and is checked) in the `RewriteRule` line anyway. It is possible to handle this as you do, just not useful.

Comment: You are wrong, without `%{REQUEST_URI}` you will not be able to detect if the user wrote `domain.local/gp` unless you use `%{REQUEST_URI}` where `%{REQUEST_URI}` is equal to `gp/`, also without `\/` RewriteCond will always evaluate to false. Your answer is partially correct, anyone who facing similar issue will look for a more comprehensive answer to be honest, this is why I created this answer, so that anyone can benefit from it. I am starting to feel you are thinking the exact opposite of what I asked in the original question.